# Cannot login after editing /etc/fstab

Tags: server, login, fstab, nfs

I've recently changed my `/etc/fstab` to mount `/home` to a NFS. After rebooting, I cannot login anymore. The system doesn't respond after I enter my password. What options do I have now?

Comment: I would startup from a live usb or dvd, navigate to the `/etc/fstab` file on your disk (computer ->) and undo the changes you made. (`sudo -i gedit /path/to/...`)

Comment: Looks like your NFS home is not exported correctly or not mounted when you try to login, therefore you can't login. Did you try to login in text mode? Press `CTRL+ALT+1` A black screen should appear with a prompt: login; Enter your username, press Enter and type your password (not visible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restart your computer and access recovery mode using the grub menu. Select "Drop to root shell prompt" and use nano or vim or whatever other text editor you have to undo the changes or simply use the copy and rename commands to reinstate you backup.

[How to Access and Use Your Linux Distribution’s Boot Loader](http://www.howtogeek.com/196520/grub2-101-how-to-access-and-use-your-linux-distributions-boot-loader/)